# Angular 6 change global css based on criteria

Tags: css, angular

I have a requirement as follows:
A site has many elements, buttons, text box etc which need to change font-size, colour etc based on the user that is logged in. What is the best way to achieve this? eg if user A is logged in, the buttons on the site should be green, for user B blue for user c yellow etc. The whole css needs to change based on who has logged in. My initial thoughts is to somehow use Angular universal. Any thoughts, suggestions?

Comment: You should create a settings Javascript object per user (maybe save in DB too). For example : `{ fontSize: '16px', backgroundColor: 'blue'}` and attach it dynamicaly in your template thanks to `[ngStyle]` directive like @JigneshMisty show you

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is solution for this. Similar was my issue. I used switch case to circle between colors of users. Below is the code for that using ngStyle

HTML

```
<span style="width:100%;color: #fff;padding: 3%;border-radius: 5px;" [ngStyle]="{'background-color':getColor(a.actions[0])}">
            {{a.actions[0]}}
          </span> &nbsp;
          <span style="width:100%;color: #fff;padding: 3%;border-radius: 5px;" [ngStyle]="{'background-color':getColor(a.actions[1])}">
            {{a.actions[1]}}
          </span>
```

TS PART

```
getColor(color) {
    switch (color) {
      case 'Enable':
        return 'green';
      case 'Perma Disable':
        return 'red';
      case 'Temp Disable':
        return 'purple';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set only background-color:

```
<button [style.backgroundColor]="getColor()" ...></button>
```

TS

```
  getColor(){
    if(user.something=='A')
      return 'blue'
    .
    .
    .
    }
```

If you want to **set a few styles** I recommand you use `ngClass`:

```
<div [ngClass]="user.something"><div>
```

in css:

```
.a{
...
}
.b{
...
}
```